# Can you smooth mains A.C?

Tags: capacitor, ac, smoothing-capacitor

I know you can smooth DC with a capacitor but what if you have an unstable mains AC voltage (here in the UK that's 240V 50Hz)? Are there components that can be used or products one can make/buy for the same sort of end goal, a more constant supply?

Comment: You need an AC-DC-AC converter

Comment: There are a number of options (including motor-generators, AC/DC/AC converter, Constant voltage transformer...). You should edit your question to say what type of AC power you have (e.g. 1 phase 50Hz 230V?), what is wrong with your AC (Transients? Brownouts? short dropouts? Varying voltage? Varying frequency?) and what you need to provide power to (Motor? Resistive load? SMPS?).

Comment: Why do you want a 'constant' AC supply?

Comment: If you truly need one, buy. Don't build because this is on the high-end of power projects.

Comment: @Chu so our lights don't flicker. LEDs are quite sensitive unlike incandescent

Comment: Higher-end UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supplies) have this function. It's called a Double Conversion On-Line UPS.

Comment: @Mr.Boy, Flickering LEDs might very well be caused by other things than an unstable mains voltage.

Comment: it seems if you can notice the lights dimming for long periods, a voltage regulator alone or a voltage regulator with a UPS would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

In countries such as India where power is not always reliable there are voltage stabilizers available that reduce variations in voltage and protect things like compressors (as in refrigerators, air conditioning etc.) that can be damaged by brownout.

Most are of one of two kinds- the first (relay type) has a transformer with taps inside and some electromechanical relays that connect the taps in or out of phase with the incoming mains to add or subtract voltage.

The second (servo type) has a motor-driven variable transformer that adds or subtracts voltage from the incoming mains.

Typically they also have an over/under-voltage disconnect function if the incoming mains is so high or low that they cannot correct it.

It should be **unnecessary** in the UK- in fact wide power fluctuations might be symptomatic of a problem with your wiring that could cause a fire. You might want to check with an electrician if that's a possibility.

Comment: A third option that is similar to the servo controller is to implement PWM directly on the AC supply, using two pairs of series source-to-source connected MOSFETs or IGBTs with duty cycle adjusted to compensate for mains voltage variations. If the variation is only 10%, a 1 kVA buck/boost transformer could be used for a 10 kVA service. 100% duty cycle adds (or subtracts) the full buck/boost voltage, and 0% just bypasses the transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not in a useful way.

The simplest equivalent is to use an LC bandpass filter.  This works around a center frequency of the mains, in exactly the same way as a lowpass filter works around a center frequency of 0 (DC).

This is still not exactly equivalent to the common DC filter circuit, which uses rectifiers into a capacitor -- it is nonlinear -- but if we remove that specific nonlinearity, the behavior isn't grossly different, and the AC equivalent is easy to construct.

Then, what values might be needed?

If we wish to have a hold-up time of say 100ms, we need a bandwidth of around 10Hz or a Q of 6 at 60Hz mains.

The impedance, however, is an interesting question.  Filters are normally designed for a matched source and/or load.  But our source is extremely low impedance (under 0.1 ohm?) and our load is variable (whatever's plugged in).  We will need to provide termination somehow to prevent it from bouncing, and an output impedance low enough that the remaining amount of "bounce" (more formally: the resulting peak change in voltage, from a change in load current, such as a rectangular step change) is acceptable.

So, if we desire 10% regulation (i.e. 12V change out of 120V input) for say a 10A load, that's an impedance of 1 ohm (which will also be a short-circuit current of 120A, since this is a linear circuit, at least for now).

Now we can calculate, if not the exact values (a topology hasn't been given yet, either), then at least the ballpark values of L and C.

These are:
$$ L = \frac{Z_0}{2 \pi F_0} $$
$$ C = \frac{1}{2 \pi Z_0 F_0} $$

We get L = 2.6mH and C = 2.6mF.  Since reactances are 1 ohm and applied voltage is 120V, they will both carry 120A circulating current, so must be rated for 14.4kVAR.  This is a rather large polyproplene capacitor, and an even bigger iron-core inductor.  To keep efficiency high, say above 80%, losses must be under 20% of the maximum load, which was 10A at 120V or 1.2kW, so 240W is the budget.  With 14.4kVAR circulating, the minimum combined Q factor is 14.4/0.24 = 60, which will be a challenge to meet with an iron-core inductor (perhaps requiring thinner (more expensive) laminations than usual, and thicker copper than otherwise).  (The capacitor, as usual, should have a much higher Q, leaving the inductor the critical component.)

Note that the inductor must handle at least 170A peak without saturating, and with saturation defined to a fairly narrow threshold of maybe -10 or -20% of nominal, since the wave-averaged reduction in value will shift the resonant frequency, once running at operating voltage.  That is, as inductor current reaches its peak, inductance is momentarily reduced by saturation, momentarily raising the resonant frequency; the effect, averaged over a full cycle, must result in a shift much less than the bandwidth, so, say less than 8% shift, which corresponds to about 15% inductance shift.  Although, that's only at the peaks, and I don't know how much it'll average out by, but perhaps a more regular -30% saturation threshold would be acceptable here.

Also of consideration, running steel at saturation essentially maximizes hysteresis loss, regardless(?) of sheet thickness; it may still be required to operate at lower flux density just to keep Q factor high.  Or more expensive and specialized materials might be required (nanocrystalline?).

Additional issues are the immense startup (inrush surge) current likely requiring a soft-start circuit, or the huge transient current available under fault conditions.

Regarding that last point: the capacitor can discharge much more quickly than mains can by itself; it isn't actually much energy (37J), but it can be released in a short time scale.  Basically limited by the RC time constant of the capacitance and whatever wiring is attached.  (Probably resistance dominates so we can ignore inductance or reversal (no ringing).)

The amount of energy required, is fairly easily stored -- 2.6mF worth of 200V electrolytics fit in your hand -- but the problem is delivery.  (Electrolytics are even available in applicable ratings -- AC motor start caps for example -- but they do not have nearly high enough Q for the above network.)  Clearly, a passive network isn't such a great method, and so we opt for the more complicated, technological solution, which ends up better overall (compact, cheap, etc.) -- typically a rectifier to DC then inverter back to AC.  An intermediate DC supply is also easy to back up with batteries, as in a UPS (good for interruptions of minutes to hours).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a mains surge suppressor. They are cheap and might work if the problem is excess spikes on the mains. Do the LED lights flicker if driven from a wall circuit rather than lighting circuit? If so, try the suppressor. If not, then it is something else